# Deploy legacy .net framework console application to on prem server using Azure DevOps CICD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, console-application, pipeline

I am new to DevOps and CICD pipelines.
I successfully deployed ASP .NET MVC website using Azure DevOps CICD pipeline to my onprem agent/machine using Azure DevOps.

> Similarly I want to deploy a console application which can be
>   ultimately used as scheduled job in windows 'Task Scheduler' or either
>   as a 'Windows Service'. Right now I am managing these deployments
>   manually but after seeing the power of DevOps I hope, there could be
>   really some automated solution for console apps as well.

*The applications are built in legacy framework like 3.5 to 4.5, so not .net core apps.*
I found lot of online articles which demonstrates deploying webjobs on azure or may be possible for onprem but is it possible for old console apps?

I tried to build a very simple console app in Framework 4.7 and tried to deploy/copy/publish to my onprem machine's shared path. Gave permission to VSTS agent services which are running but copy files and publish artifact tasks are failing. I tried to do it in both CI and CD pipelines but all are failing.

**Please review the pipelines and logs** and suggest where I am doing wrong or there are any alternatives?
[https://dev.azure.com/MSTCsandippatel/DemoConsoleApp](https://dev.azure.com/MSTCsandippatel/DemoConsoleApp/_build)

> 2019-11-05T05:03:52.8436105Z ##[error]Publishing build artifacts
>   failed with an error: Unable to create directory '\MAHANTAM\Azure
>   Artifacts\DemoConsoleApp'. Unable to verify the directory exists:
>   '\MAHANTAM\Azure Artifacts\DemoConsoleApp'. If directory is a file
>   share, please verify the share name is correct, the share is online,
>   and the current process has permission to access the share.

CI pipeline 1

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=True /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'DemoConsoleApp'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=True /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'DemoConsoleApp'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

CI pipeline 2

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    vstsFeed: '622d44e2-69d4-4d42-bb91-9d6ddd97f9ba/8eaf9077-829d-4567-93c0-8e0d7973634b'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files Task'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**/**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: DemoConsoleApp'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: DemoConsoleApp
```

[image]

[image: Deployment group - machine]

Comment: Failing with what error? If you are deploying on-prem, it's probably easier to provision an on-premise Deployment Agent

Comment: I accessed your DevOps and captured the error. (BTW You linked to the wrong area) It looks like a normal access error. Can you explain what the deploy step does / is as we don't have access.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nick.McDermaid. This is for learning purpose only where I am trying to figure out how to setup CICD for console apps. Ultimately I have to deploy it on multiple servers where there is already setup of scheduled jobs and win services.
In deployment I just need to copy the bin folder to uat/prod server. Copy exe+config +dlls which I do manually every time currently.

Comment: Are you using Hosted Azure Pipelines? This is a cloud machine that is not going to have access to your shared drive. Or are you using a self hosted agent?

Comment: I tried to change parameters in CD pipeline image above but no luck.
I am using 'Deployment groups' option where my machine is registered, seems online and where I deployed the MVC webapp as well.

Comment: Did you install an agent as per here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: No, I just ran the powershell script to connect with my machine. But let me try as per your link.

Comment: In the build pipeline under "Agent Job"  then "Agent Selection", I guess the agent pool is "Azure Pipelines" right? This is an Azure hosted agent that doesn't know anything at all about your on-premises resources. You need to install a self hosted agent and link it to DevOps then you can run it on there, and it will be able to access your local file share (assuming local security is set up correctly)

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick.McDermaid, you are right. I need to setup agent and 'Azure Pipelines' runs on cloud, so it has no idea about my shared path. Now, after creating self-hosted agent, it copies file. But I messed with the CD pipeline so it copies source code as well! 
Do you think I need to fix my CI pipeline as well? I will try to fix CD in case if it can just copy the exe or zip with executable. 
I am trying to make it work since two weeks and finally it seems I would make it soon.

Comment: When you publish the artifact in the build step, use a file filter that does not include your source code. Then your artifact will not contain any source code. There's nothing wrong with starting again completely with new build and deploy pipelines and taking careful note of each step.

Comment: i.e. in the _Stage Artifacts_ step in the _Contents_ window, use something like `**\bin\**` to only capture files within the bin folder

Comment: Actually, it was creating entire folder structure from solution to release folder. So, I selected the 'Release' folder as 'Source Folder' in the 'Copy Files' task in CD pipeline and used ** to copy all release files - config, exe etc. Finally the goal is achieved. Thnx for your quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Agent Pool "Azure Pipelines" for your agent, the deployment will occur on an azure cloud machine which doesn't know anything about your on-premise machines.

[image]

You should install a self-hosted agent on-premise and link that to your DevOps and use that for the agent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: I still have one isseue, somehow the changes are not being reflected and I checked in CD that it selects latest build artifact. But somehow the EXE is not being updated. Below is YAML of CD pipeline and CI is visible in source code.

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DemoConsoleApp/DemoConsoleApp/ConsoleApp2/bin/Release'
    TargetFolder: '\\MAHANTAM\Azure Artifacts\DemoConsoleApp\'

Comment: 1. Download the build artifact (from within DevOps) and ensure that it's the one you expect. 2. You can also delete the files in the target folder and confirm that they are copied in. My guess is you're not copying the correct build folder or something.